# How to download image in iOS?

Tags: ionic-framework, amcharts

When trying to download an image with the library am charts in ionic, it works in the browser but not when I put it in iOS.

It shows me this error

[image]

This is the code of the export method:

```
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "menu": [{
          "class": "export-main",
          "menu": [{
            "label": "Descargar",
            "menu": ["PNG", "JPG", "PDF"]
          }]
        }]
      }
```

Comment: Post the code and error messages as text, not as images.

Comment: sorry, i did it